# ispell in emacs exits with error code 2 after upgrading emacs

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I recently upgraded my emacs to version 24.3.1 on ubuntu (I had a lower 24 version before). I first purged the old version and the installed the current version to get a clean update. Since, then cannot use ispell anymore.

First, I got an error message stating that there is not such function or program. I checked: ispell was installed. I then specified the path to ispell using

```
setq ispell-program-name.
```

Then doing so, I got an error message that permission is denied. So I changed permission (chmod aou+wrx) for the file. Now I get the following error message:

```
ispell.el exited with code 2.
```

This happens whether I evoked ispell-region or ispell-word.

I also installed ispell by hand on my home site-lisp and loaded that fiel, with the same result.

Any suggestions about the meaning of the code would be helpful.

Thanks! Stephan

Answer (score 1):

You should **not** set the path to `ispell.el` -- instead the path should be to an executable program like `aspell` -- e.g.:

```lisp
(setq-default ispell-program-name "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/elpa/bin/aspell")
```

You do **not** need to check to see whether `ispell.el` is installed because it automatically comes with a full version of Emacs.  Instead, you need to install something like `aspell` if you don't already have it installed. You also need to install the language dictionary used by `aspell` -- e.g., English dictionary.  Here is a link you may find helpful regarding installing `aspell` on Ubuntu:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/aspell

Think of `ispell.el` as a front-end, which has useful functions to operate a separately installed spelling program like `aspell` -- with a separately installed dictionary database (e.g., English).

Comment: Thanks -- that worked! Not sure why I did not have to specify this before.